# I am trying to make a popup box within a table

Tags: html

I am filling in a table using php and have two images that I can click on that will show me two different popup boxes - each of which is a table as well, although I don't think that matters.

I need to keep these inner table within the table so as to get the right data populating from php (details or notes about the table line I'm on now.)

I have the popups as display:none and then after the button click I used .show() in jquery to display the popup.

What I don't like is underneath my table row, I get a very small extra row that I don't want to see, when I show the popup.  The popup is position: absolute right now.  When I made it relative that extra row is huge so that's even worse.

Here's the HTML once data is populated in it.  I've removed the second popup as it's really the same thing.

```
<div class="container">         
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">                 
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>                     
                .....
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="notesExpanderButton"><img src='images/notes.jpg' title='notes' style="width:35px;height:25px;"></button>
                        <button class="detailsExpanderButton"><img src='images/details.png' title='details' style="width:35px;height:25px;"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>Job 5</td>
                    <td>01/01/2015</td>
                    <td>Client Name</td>
                    </td>111 Somewhere Street</td>
                .....
                </tr> 
                <td class="detailsOuter">
                    <div class="detailsData" id=Job5>
                            <table class='table-borderless detailsTable'>
                                 <thead>
                                    <th colspan="4">Details: Job 5</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                   .....            
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                </tbody>    
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. You posted the HTML, which looks like it involves Bootstrap, but no CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The table is malformed.  You currently have this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <td>...</td>
</table>
```

`td` elements need to be *inside* `tr` elements, not alongside them.  What you want is this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Change your server-side code to generate the table with the correct cell positions and strange whitespace issues should go away.  You may of course still need to continue changing your styling, but at the very least the styling will be easier to debug and adjust if the markup is valid.

Note: You also have a typo in the opening `td` tag on this element:

```
</td>111 Somewhere Street</td>
```

Which is more invalid markup.

---

Though... If the only content in this table cell is a "popup", which itself is visually separate from the table, then it *probably* doesn't belong in a table cell in the first place.  It should probably be its own element outside of the table.

Usually "popups" (or "modal divs") are kept in some collection at the end of the markup, styled to be hidden.

Comment: Ignore the invalid markup as I was editing the html manually and cutting out things, so I may have messed up.  The only thing wrong is the inner table is only within a <td> but not within a <tr>.  I did originally have a <tr> as well which I think gave me the extra table row as well - maybe even before the button click that's why I removed it.  I was thinking I could copy (something I read about) the html that I want and in jquery add it back to the body or somewhere outside the table - would that make sense?

Comment: @shoshana: If the content isn't actually part of the table then it certainly makes sense to put it outside of the table.  I can't really speak to why jQuery would be the way to accomplish that.  The question has only static HTML, so in that case you'd just statically change the HTML.  You mention that PHP is being used server-side, so I imagine the PHP could generate the page rather than involving JavaScript.

Comment: I meant to say javascript when I said jquery.   I guess I could reloop through all the popup type of data in php after I've created the table (as right now I was ouputting the appropriate notes and comments for each row in the table as I created the table).  I would just have to include ids in the (new) popup tables to help me find what I want.  Alternatively, I could leave the popups where they are, but copy them with javascript to a different part of the DOM before show()ing them.  I think I'll be ok.  Thank you.

Comment: @shoshana: It seems kind of silly to leave them where they are for the sole purpose of moving them, when you can just move them in the first place.  Unless there are *many* elements, a loop isn't really an expensive operation.  As an alternative, you *can* keep it inside the table.  Just make sure it's in an actual table cell so that the overall markup is still valid.

Comment: There are definitely many elements.  I could loop a second time, I guess, I'll see.     But I wouldn't mind if you can tell me a way to keep it as a table within the table and avoid the extra table row showing up.  (I PUT BACK the <tr> - so my HTML is correct) but I still get an empty skinny row that I don't want.  Should I tell it a height of zero? If there's no way to fix this then I'll put the notes outside the table.

Comment: @shoshana: If you made a new, empty `<tr>` then that would indeed be a new, empty row.  (Empty in the sense that it only contains an element which is styled to be more of a "popup".)  If that's the case then put it inside the `tr` that you already have.  Basically, avoid creating empty table rows/cells.  You can hide the modal `div` in any table cell.  If it's styled not to be visible, it won't be visible.  Creating empty cells/rows likely causes whitespace.